# Correlation between slightly misaligned images

Tags: image-processing, correlation

I am matching camera images of projection screens with rendered pages of PDF documents using [Pearson's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) and [Spearman's correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman's_rank_correlation_coefficient). When the images ([3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUei9.png), [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aL6z.png), [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLLFy.png)) are aligned, this works fine in spite of the clear shortcomings (optical aberration in the camera images, the random sample is not independent, uneven illumination, etc.).

In the figure below, Pearson's r between the left and middle images is 0.8395 and Spearman's r is 0.6499. Pearson's r between the left and right images is 0.7139 and Spearman's r is 0.5066.

[image: A camera image (left) and two rendered PDF pages (middle and right)]
[image: Histograms of the above three images]

However, when the content of the rendered PDF page differs slightly from the document in the camera image or when the images ([8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79BAC.png), [9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyAkL.png), [10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLKwL.png)) are more than slightly misaligned, the correlation coefficient ceases to be useful.

In the figure below, Pearson's r between the left and middle images is 0.771 and Spearman's r is 0.4719. Pearson's r between the left and right images is 0.779 and Spearman's r is 0.4963.

[image: A camera image (left) and two rendered PDF pages (middle and right)]
[image: Histograms of the above three images]

Reducing the images to density estimates (i.e. discarding the pixel positions and comparing histograms) would likely remove valuable information. Non-feature-based image registration seems like a more promising direction. What technique would you recommend to attack this problem?

Comment: why not use features like SURF and do a comparison based on these?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I am going to try feature-based matching separately. However, some of the camera images have an alarmingly small signal-to-noise ratio, which is going to make feature extraction difficult. Since the images are well-aligned, I though correlation, which expects very little from the input signal, or a related non-feature-based similarity measure might work well.

Comment: Total guess as I do not do image processing but it sounds similar to the purpose of doing a cross correlation function in that you compute the correlation at all delay offsets (as often there is a delay mismatch that such an approach would pick up). So in this case could it make sense to compute the correlation with a 2D pixel offset parameter (repeating it for all offsets)?

Comment: Finding a translation that maximizes the correlation might work nicely! Although perhaps not all the possible offsets, but just a small neighborhood of (0, 0), so that it does not take ages to compute.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added results of further experiments as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Dan Boschen](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/21048/dan-boschen), I maximized the Spearman's correlation coefficient over all possible “small” translations – where small is less than 15 pixels in L1-distance – of the rendered PDF page images. The results were underwhelming, but I suppose this method would work much better if the camera images weren't optically distorted.

In the figure below, Pearson's r between the left and middle images is 0.789 and Spearman's r is 0.479. Pearson's r between the left and right images is 0.8008 and Spearman's r is 0.5094.

[image: Image registration by small translations]

As suggested by [Marcus Müller](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/13320/marcus-m%c3%bcller), I used a feature detector ([ORB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriented_FAST_and_rotated_BRIEF), not SURF) to find keypoints in the images. Rather than directly use the feature descriptors for matching, I used them to find a homography that registers the two images.

In the figure below, Pearson's r between the left and middle images is 0.6244 and Spearman's r is 0.4921. Pearson's r between the left and right images is 0.0213 and Spearman's r is 0.036. For my test case, this works remarkably well.

[image: Image registration by feature matching]

Comment: Nice work! Very interesting.